# I have a long error message when writing "python manage.py makemigrations" saying invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, manage.py, makemigrations

1**. I am following Mosh' tutorial on (youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc)- at the part where we get to the DB SQLite part, it sayd this long message when writing "Python manage.py makemigrations":

`(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop>python manage.py makemigrations
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 376, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
    line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\pyshop\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", 
    line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
    line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PyShop\products\urls.py", line 7
    path('new', views.new)
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax****`

2. On his tutorial he also dragged the db.sqlite3 document from Pycharm to the DB browser and when I try to do it it says "No database file opened" 
   I don't think it's - could it be because I installed it wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: This problem seems to be syntax error, check in `products\urls.py` and inside `urlpatterns` you should check this line `("new",views.new)`. Possibility is you might have forgot a `,` as urlpatterns is array of tuples. Check it and let me know.

Comment: This is how I have it written (for some reason I can't comment it like a code, it pastes it all in one line):


urlpatterns = [
    path(' ', views.index)
    path('new', views.new)
]

Comment: comma is missing before second path and also the quotes are missing. Use this code, this should solve your problem `urlpatterns=[ path("",views.index),path("new",views.new)]`

Comment: When I just write in this one statement path("", views.index) it works and the browser shows "Hello world"
When I add path('new', views.new) - exactly the way you and he in the tutorial wrote it, it says 404 error not found

What can it be? (I did add the coma, there's nothing seems to be missing now)

Comment: `404 error not found` is a new error, so you need to [edit] your question and add the full traceback of the new error.